# How to implement console logging in ASP.NET Core MVC Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

I’m learning ASP.NET Core and playing with fundamental stuff, but I wasn't able to enable logging in the application. How do i make it work?

I've been looking to the documentation and comparing my code to the one provided as a sample in the microsoft documentation, but i can't figure out what am i doing wrong.

Program.cs (I'm using the default builder which contains console logging provider)

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public class HomeController: Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HomeController(
            ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogCritical(_localizer["Hello"]);
            _logger.LogWarning("ASD");
            _logger.LogInformation("Getting item {ID}", 3);

            return View();
        }
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
"Logging": {
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Razor": "Debug",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "Error",
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    }
  }
```

I'm able to see the messages but only in Debug output window, while in the sample project from the microsoft documentation there is a seperate "ASP.NET Core Web Server" output window where all log messages are printed and it's more readable.

[image]

Comment: How is logging added to the service collection?

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich I haven't added/removed anything. I've read that CreateDefaultBuilder adds the following logging providers: Console, Debug, EventSource (starting in ASP.NET Core 2.2) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Maybe that's the problem, but what should i try next?

Comment: So, how the application is started then? I almost sure if in Visual Studio near the green run arrow there would be your application name selected (as a host) - you application would be started in a separate console window and you will see all the logs listed in the window appeared.

Comment: It seesm to be a know issue for asp.net core 2.2 which uses `InProcess` hosting model.Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/10307

Comment: @Xing Zou Oooh, i've read that the newest versions of visual studio have fixed this problem. I'm using slightly older version... Thanks